# Verse Error in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, verse

I am getting below error in Ubuntu 10.04, texlive 2010 
I do not get any such errors and get pdf output in my 2011 macbook running texlive 2010.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.44 \AtBeginEnvironment
                        {Verse}{\singlespacing}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.45 \AtBeginEnvironment
                        {enumerate}{\singlespacing}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.46 \AtBeginEnvironment
                        {longtable}{\onehalfspacing}
```

?

When I press enter it processes the file and gives the pdf output I am attaching the screenshot of the first page as well. The first page shows "Verse Enumerate and longtable" I could not explain why its does this. I would appreciate your help. [image]

second page onwards the document is as I wanted. Here are the two documents, one contants all the required packages (AK.tex) and 2_AK_034.tex has actual verse and its explanation.

Here is the file with all the packages https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2ORRM7gQAXeYmY0MWVhZDAtMDU3My00OTNkLTliMzAtNDEwOWY4YzBjZjcw&hl=en_US

Here is the actual tex file that contains all the verse and explanation. 
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B2ORRM7gQAXeYjZlYTVmMDEtNTNjZC00NGU3LWEzOGYtNTFkMDUyZGVmMDky&hl=en_US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says that `\AtBeginEnvironment` is undefined. This command is defined in the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. So ensure that this package is loaded. Consider to install that package if it's missing, or update it if it's not the current version. The most recent version of `etoolbox` is 2.1.

Comment: In fact, it formed part of the most recent addition to `etoolbox` (2011-01-03).

Comment: I would appreciate if you can tell me how can I update etoolbox package? Also how can I check if I have latest etoolbox package.

Comment: @Aku: On the command line (in a terminal window) type `kpsewhich etoolbox.sty` to find the directory of the package. There should be two files, `etoolbox.sty` and `etoolbox.def`. The version is written in the beginning of those files. Also, the version is printed to the `.log` file of your document. You can download the package from CTAN and replace it there, or you could install it to your personal TeX home directory. Package installation has often been described on the site, search for it or post a new question if necessary.

Comment: @Stefan-thanks for your help, it worked, I had to replace it on my local directory.

Answer (score 4):

The `\AtBeginEnvironment` has been added to **etoolbox** version 2.1 (Jan. 3, 2011). Unfortunately, it's impossible now to update TeX Live 2010: either do a manual install or advance to TeX Live 2011.